# Curly brace error occurring when curly braces are closed correctly

Tags: latex, syntax-error, curly-braces

As title says I get error:

```
line 55: Missing { inserted ... $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i v_i =O_\vec{E}
line 55: Missing } inserted ...v_n \in A =>\lambda_i =0,...,\lambda_n =0$
: Not defining \perthousand.
: Not defining \micro.
```

The exact line and its context are:

```latex
 \begin{itemize} 
     \item On dit que A est \textit{libre} si le seule c. l. de vecteurs de A egales a $O_E$ est la c. l. triviale.
     \item C'est-a-dire si: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i v_i =O_\vec{E}, v_1...v_n \in A =>\lambda_i =0,...,\lambda_n =0$$
\end{itemize}
```

The packages I have imported are:

```latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=.75in, a4paper, portrait]{geometry}
```

Comment: Don't write `=>`. Either `\Rightarrow` or `\geq` or `\geqslant` (see http://write-math.com to find your symbol)

Comment: And please copy the complete (minimzied) document. This includes `\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}`. That makes it easier for others to understand and fix your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here stems from the somewhat greedy nature of the subscript routine when you use

```
O_\vec{E}
```

It grabs `\vec` *without* it's argument giving rise to the problem. Here are my suggestions to fix your situation:

- Don't use `$$`...`$$`. Instead, use `\[`...`\]` (see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764));
- Ellipsis are defined in LaTeX; with [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) you can use *smart* `\dots`;
- Relations should be used, so `\implies` (say) instead of `=>`

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} 
  \item Here is some \textit{regular} text, mixed in with $O_E$ some math.
  \item And a display equation:
    \[
      \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i v_i 
        = O_{\vec{E}}, v_1,\dots,v_n \in A 
        \implies \lambda_i = 0,\dots,\lambda_n 
        = 0
    \]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```